# My computer may be dead. Help!

Tags: macbook-pro, performance, repair

Early 2011 13" MBP, formerly 500GB HDD but changed to a 620GB DIY Fusion Drive a few weeks ago. I've been on Yosemite since the first days of the Public Beta, but starting earlier today my computer started crashing every time I tried to do anything. A verify/repair took more than 20 minutes, and a permissions verify took so long that I gave up on trying to wait it out. Even when I came home to my bootable OS X USB drive, everything hung: A disk verify, a permissions repair, and even an OS reinstall all found themselves hanging. Eventually I decided to do a total wipe/restore, but even then the OS X reinstall got stuck. I'm ready to admit that it may be a hardware problem, but without my disk drive I have no way of running Apple Hardware Test. Two questions: What other troubleshooting can I attempt, and where can I go to get my computer looked at and fixed despite its modified hardware?

Comment: How about Safe mode? or Verbose mode ? Actually it sounds like your HDD is the problem.

Comment: Safe Mode starts with a fsck check that, as I can tell you from experience, isn't any less hang-y than the Disk Utility check. And, with the one exception of a Safe Mode boot, the startup itself never hangs, so I'm not sure how helpful Verbose Mode would be.

Comment: I'm thinking of splitting the Fusion Drive and seeing how the SSD performs by itself.

Comment: Verbose will tell you where it hangs up.